# Prove that if $g(x)$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ then the following holds.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{g(x)}t^2dt$. Prove that $F'(x) = g(x)^2.g'(x)$ for all $x \in R$. If $G(x) = \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}t^2dt$, then what is $G'(x)$?

Let $f(t) = t^2$. Since $f(t)$ is a continuous function then the anti derivative of $f(t)$ exists such that $H'(t) = f(t) , \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $.

Let $\frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h} = \frac{\int_{g(x)}^{g(x+h)}t^2}{h} = \frac{H(g(x+h)) - H(g(x))}{h} = H(g(x))' = H'(g(x)).g'(x).$

Since $t^2$ is a continuous function so $H'(g(x)) = f(g(x)) = (g(x))^2$. [By second fundamental theorem of calculus]

So we conclude that $H'(g(x))g'(x) = g(x)^2.g'(x)$.

Let $\frac{G(x+r) - G(x)}{r} = \frac{\int_{0}^{h(x+r)}t^2 - \int_{0}^{h(x)}t^2 + \int_{0}^{g(x)}t^2 - \int_{0}^{g(x+r)}t^2}{r} = \frac{H(h(x+r)) - H(h(x))}{r} - \frac{H(g(x+r)-H(g(x))}{r} = H(h(x))' - H(g(x))' = H'(h(x)).h'(x) - H'(g(x)).g'(x) = h(x)^2.h'(x) - g(x)^2.g'(x)$

> I want comeone to go through my attempt.
>
> Is there any general formula for evaluate integrals like $G(x) = \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(t)$ where $f(t)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Do you want $G(x)$ or $G'(x)$?

Comment: $G'(x)=f(g(x))g'(x)-f(h(x)) h'(x)$.

Comment: @KentaS I want someone to go through my attempt of finding $G'(x)$ . I am also asking if there is a general formula to evaluate $G(x)$?

Comment: $G(x)=\frac 1 3(h(x))^{3} -\frac 1 3(g(x))^{3} $

Comment: For the 2nd part let $F_g(x)=\int_0^{g(x)}t^2dt$ and let $F_h(x)=\int_0^{h(x)}t^2dt.$ By the 1st part we have $F_g'(x)=g(x)^2g'(x)$ and $F_h'(x)=h(x)^2h'(x).$ And we have $G(x)=\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}t^2dt=F_h(x)-F_g(x).$  (This is the method!) So $G'(x)=F_h'(x)-F_g'(x).$

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the limit, as $h\rightarrow 0$ in your difference quotients.  Let $F(t)$ be an antiderivative of $f(t).$ Then $\int_0^{g(x)}f(t)dt=F(g(x))-F(0)$ (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). So the chain rule gives you that $$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^{g(x)}f(t)dt)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(g(x))-F(0)\right)=F'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)-0=f(g(x))g'(x).$$ Similarly,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}f(t)dt)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(g(x))-F(h(x))\right)=F'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)-F'(h(x))h'(x)=f(g(x))g'(x)-f(h(x))h'(x).$$